# PHP Memory Cleared when using exit()?

Tags: php, ajax, apache, memory-leaks, exit

My web app makes a lot of POST and GET calls via AJAX to my PHP scripts. I've noticed my server's memory usage is reaching a pretty low level after calling my scripts when exporting to PDF/excel, searching, inserting/updating/deleting, etc.

None of my PHP scripts end with `exit()` or `die()`. Could this be causing my memory issue? If I were to add `exit()` or `die()` at the end of each script, would this clear the memory that was just used by that given script?

Comment: what libs are you using to export PDF and Excel -- I would suspect those to be the culprits more likely than PHP itself.

Comment: I use TCPDF for my PDF exporting... I don't use a lib for my Excel exports

Comment: PHP already cleans up used memory when a script exits. just because your code doesn't have an explicity exit() or die() calls doesn't mean the server magically keeps it running somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `exit()` or `die()` would make any difference.

Please ensure you free database resources (result sets, connections, etc...). Moreover, consider all the extensions you use and ensure none of them has known bugs regarding memory leaks, especially if you use exotic extensions.

If you are on Linux and your server is not swapping on disk even if the "free memory" is "low", **this could be due to disk caching**. In that case, everything is fine. See: [linuxatemyram.com](http://linuxatemyram.com).
BTW, where do you get the information about the free memory?

Comment: LOL... love that site and it really makes sense. I thought my "free" ram was at 16 MB when in reality, after reading through that site, I see that I still have 360 MB free. I am using the command `free -m` to see my current usage

Comment: I accepted this answer since it allowed me to realize how much of a Linux newbie I am, and that I really don't have a memory problem caused by PHP! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

`exit` and `die` are basically the same as reaching the end of the file. Destructors are run, `ob_start` levels are flushed and ended, and any shutdown functions are run.

At the end of any PHP process, however, the process ends just like any other program. No memory is left over.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a PHP issue, its an Apache feature.

When a apache starts a new process to handle your request, it doesn't immediately dispose its resources after your request has been handled, instead, it stays available for any possible future requests.

If you use 'top' command, you will see multiple apache processes running.

Read about it here: http://abdussamad.com/archives/169-Apache-optimization:-KeepAlive-On-or-Off.html